# Chai/Node.js: Expect(value).to.be.NaN issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I have these form fields I need to validate with chai expect. They all work (I get errors) except for the fields that require characters - expect(value).to.be.NaN is not working... The code:

```
var inputs = [response.fname, response.surname,
  response.age, response.password
];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var stackErrors = validate(i);
  console.log(stackErrors);
}

function validate(i) {
  var fields = inputs[i];

  try {
    if (i == 0) {
      expect(fields).to.be.Nan;
    }

    if (i == 1) {
      expect(fields).to.be.Nan;
    }

    if (i == 2) {
      expect(fields).not.to.be.NaN;
    }

    if (i == 3) {
      expect(fields).to.have.length.above(6);
    }

    return "OK";
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

But if test the field like in the example bellow, right after the inputs array, I get the expected assertion error...:

```
expect(inputs[0]).to.be.NaN;
```

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @Lazyexpert (I've noticed you have Nan in your code, it is not the same as NaN.), I found the obvious solution...(a case sensitive issue, actualy)

```
try {
    if (i == 0) {
      expect(fields).to.be.NaN; //instead of Nan...
    }
```

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please accept this as an answer (click the green checkmark underneath the arrows to the left).

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. Well, please remember to! ;)

Comment: It seems strange to me, that I've pointed you your error and you add the similar answer... Don't you think so?

Comment: @Lazyexpert I got the solution thanks to your hint, but your answer is not explicit like mine. But if you want to edit your post and put it like I did, I'll give you the credit :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this code:

```
Number.isNaN(NaN) // true
```

And:

```
Number.isNaN(5) // false
```

I would do a small workaround(just to make it fast), something like this:

```
expect(Number.isNaN(inputs[0])).to.be.eq(false);
```

**UPDATE:**
I've noticed you have Nan in your code, it is not the same as NaN.

I'm not sure how it is implemented, but as far as it is chained, try this:

```
expect(undefined).to.be.eq.Nan
```

I think you should receive true in this case.

Comment: with your update I still dont get assertion errors...I type in a number and it passes..

Comment: and as for this statement `expect(Number.isNaN(inputs[0])).to.be.eq(false);` the program ignores it...

Comment: well i found the error...if you check my code I have ´Nan` instead of ´NaN`...now it works...thanks anyway @Lazyexpert :)